# UpsertLogicalServerRequestAlreadyInProgress when trying to create Azure SQL Logical Server

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-sql-server

I have Azure DevOpe pipeline, which have worked fine so fine, but yesterday I got suddenly showstopper error. Pipeline gave no error, but SQL Logical Server was not created.
I deleted all resources in Resource group. Then I executed pipeline again. I'm getting "An ongoing logical server request is already in progress, please try your request again later" error. It has been already 24 hours that I have been not able to create Logical Server.

I thought that I could just cancel deployment from Azure portal, but I don't see any deployment with error. What I could do?

ERROR on Azure DevOps:

```
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive - 
ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\43a1dcab-bbff-4fd8-8cc7-5773945858fa.ps1'"
Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_4.3.0\Az.Accounts\1.9.1\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 
-Environment AzureCloud @processScope
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 0000000000000000000 -TenantId ***
strtempdigiopsdev
##[error]9:15:12 AM - The deployment 'TemplateMasterDeployment' failed with error(s). Showing 2 out 
of 2 error(s).
Status Message: The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'. (Code: 
ResourceDeploymentFailure)
 - An ongoing logical server request is already in progress, please try your request again later. 
(Server Name: sql-srv-dev, RequestId: 2dea2656-e3dd-40b8-a7e0-c72cfe4e5bba, SubscriptionId: 
0000000000000000000 , ResourceGroup: rg-az-dev) 
(Code:UpsertLogicalServerRequestAlreadyInProgress)


Status Message: The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'. (Code: 
ResourceDeploymentFailure)
 - At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. 
Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details. (Code: DeploymentFailed)
   - {
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
  "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
 "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
 "details": [
  {
    "code": "UpsertLogicalServerRequestAlreadyInProgress",
    "message": "An ongoing logical server request is already in progress, please try your request again later. (Server Name: sql-srv-dev, RequestId: 2dea2656-e3dd-40b8-a7e0-c72cfe4e5bba, SubscriptionId: 0000000000000000000 , ResourceGroup: rg-az-dev)"
  }
]
```

}
} (Code:Conflict)

Comment: We have the same problem since last week.

Comment: has anyone found solution to this problem?

Comment: we raised a ticket with microsoft and they agreed that this is a bug and they are fixing it.

Comment: When are they going to fix it... I just got it again.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by deleting the resource group itself.

Comment: that's not a solution my friend